# Cannot do Geo and Lrange in Spring Data Redis

Tags: spring-data-redis

Spring data redis doesn't seem to support the new geohash in Redis 3.2, also the template ops for list doesn't have a method to do lrange or essentially paginate the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LRANGE` command can be used via `RedisOperations.opsForList().range(key, start, stop)` or directly using `RedisConnection.lRange(key, start, stop)`.

Support for `GEO` operations will be part of the [Ingalls](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Ingalls#spring-data-redis---18) release and is already available in the current 1.8.0 snapshots.